# Linear Regression on Specific Points

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

How do I plot 4 lines of linear regression based on colored points with the same color (using the same color for the line as well)?

**Current Graph:**

[image]

**Code:**

Note:

y_tilde = Cigarettes Smoked Per Day

x_1 = Father's Age

x_2 = Years of Education

```
print(ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(y=y_tilde, x=x_1, col=x_2)) 
  + xlab("Father's Age")
  + ylab("Cigarettes Smoked Per Day")
  + labs(color="Years of Education") 
  + geom_point(aes(colour = cut(x_2, breaks=c(-Inf, 10, 12, 14, 16), labels=c(10, 12, 14, 16)))))
```

Comment: Create your `cut()` variable beforehand (so you don't have to repeat the code) and `+ geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(colour = cut_var, fill = cut_var))` ?

Comment: With @BenBolker solution sb will get double legend without an update of `labs` so remember to update it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all start with checking out the `?aes` help page. The part `ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(y=y_tilde, x=x_1, col=x_2))` is not require specifying `col` argument inside the `aes` as you are setting it for each separate `geom`.

```r
aa <- airquality
aa$cut <- factor(aa$Month)
```

Example with sample data with one global `aes`:

```r
print(ggplot(data = aa, mapping = aes(y = Ozone, x = Temp, col = cut)) +
      xlab("Father's Age") +
      ylab("Cigarettes Smoked Per Day") +
      labs(color = "Years of Education") +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm"))
```

Example with sample data with one `aes` for each `geom`:

```r
print(ggplot(data = aa, mapping = aes(y = Ozone, x = Temp)) +
        xlab("Father's Age") +
        ylab("Cigarettes Smoked Per Day") +
        labs(color = "Years of Education") +
        geom_point(aes(col = cut)) +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(col = cut)))
```

The second thing is pointed by @BenBolker hit to use DRY rule https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY, define `cut` variable over a plot definition once. Other solution will be to use cut variable as a global `aes`, I will define such variable too to be more clear.

If you want to update the color of regression intervals too, then add to `aes` argument `fill = cut`. I changed the `labs` here too.

```r
print(ggplot(data = aa, mapping = aes(y = Ozone, x = Temp)) +
        xlab("Father's Age") +
        ylab("Cigarettes Smoked Per Day") +
        labs(color = "Years of Education", fill = "Years of Education") +
        geom_point(aes(col = cut)) +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(col = cut, fill = cut)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a global `aes`. The documentation for `aes` is just atrocious. It doesn't even tell you all its possible parameters or what `col` stands for.

Comment: Yes `col` is a tricky one as is a shortcut for `color` or an alternative `colour`,  no difference for all 3 in usage.